# Vector(synchronize) vs ArrayList(non-synchronize)

Tags: java, collections

How can we proof that the **Vector** implementation is synchronized and the **ArrayList** implementation is not synchronized even though their functionality of retrieving and storing the data is the same?

Comment: By reading their javadoc. Or their source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The source code and its documentation (if written correctly) are the only sources you can trust a 100%.** What cannot be found in there or doesn't derive from what's written in there (be careful with assumptions made if any) cannot fully be trusted! Even if you test some property and your tests show that property exist don't always make conclusions that fast and say that property is met. Read the code or the documentation first and try to deduce it from there.

In case of classes from the Java API you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) (or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html), same source, different presentation).
In the documentation from the [`ArrayList` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) it is written in bold:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.**

So you can be sure it's not synchronized.

On the documentation page of the [`Vector` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), in the last paragraph of the introduction text, the last sentences are:

> Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.

So you can be sure it is synchronized. They even recommend you not to use it if you do not need a synchronized container.